# Oracle - PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type in subtracting dates

Tags: oracle, function, date, compiler-errors, subtraction

I have troubles compiling the following function in Oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn1
return binary_double
as
Fecha  DATE;
Dias binary_double;
begin
dbms_output.put_line(CAST(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE,'DD') AS DATE) - cast(current_timestamp as date));
return Dias;
end;
```

It results in Error

```
Error(8,27): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

However running the same expression outside of function body

```
select CAST(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE,'DD') AS DATE) - cast(current_timestamp as date) from dual
```

gives the expected result - number of days between two dates

```
-0.0607060185185185185185185185185185185185
```

Is there any ideas on what could be wrong about the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE,'DD')  - cast( current_timestamp as date));
end;
/
```

Current_date returns a value of datatype DATE
Trunct also returns DATE.
So You are trying to cast DATE type to DATE type.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that PL/SQL has problem with a type casted to the same type.

`CURRENT_DATE` returns `DATE` data type so you cast it to the same type. It works in SQL but not in PL/SQL. Just remove the casting:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn1
return binary_double
as
Fecha  DATE;
Dias binary_double;
begin
dbms_output.put_line(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE,'DD') - cast(current_timestamp as date));
return Dias;
end;
```